# How to find matching string in csv file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a program that calculates the top 3 maximum value of a list of weather stations. The name of the weather stations in the top 3 are a string and determined from a sorted list (from max to min) 'maxstat' as follows:

```
txtmax = '\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(maxstat[0],
                               maxstat[1],
                               maxstat[2])
```

Where txtmax can thus be for example

```
'Baal'
'Arnhem'   
'Arendonk'
```

Now I have another csv file that I import in Python in which the country of the stations (alphabetically) is listed:

```
countrystationsfile = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'resources', 'stations_country.csv')
countrystations = pd.read_csv(countrystationsfile)
```

Where the file looks like:

[image]

```
    Place   Country Source  Comment
1   Afferden    NL  AMATEUR N/A
2   Alkmaar NL  AMATEUR N/A
3   Almelo  NL  AMATEUR N/A
4   Almere  NL  AMATEUR N/A
5   Appelscha   NL  AMATEUR N/A
6   Archenes    BE  AMATEUR N/A
7   Arendonk    BE  AMATEUR N/A
8   Arnhem  NL  AMATEUR N/A
9   Assen   NL  AMATEUR N/A
10  Avelgem BE  AMATEUR N/A
11  Baal    BE  AMATEUR N/A
```

How can I make txtmax so that it automatically searches in the countrystationsfile the corresponding matching string of the station (column Place) and as such determines its country (column Country)? In the end what I would like like is the following for txtmax:

```
'Baal, BE'
'Arnhem, NL'   
'Arendonk, BE'
```

Thanks already!

Comment: Post a short snippet of your CSV file as formatted text. Images of data are not helpful. Besides, you forgot to show your "stats" so how would we determine the top 3?

Comment: I placed it as text below the image. The string that is determined from maxstat, and the stations in the txtmax list, change all the time, because the temperature of the weather stations always changes.

Answer (score 1):

If the entries in the DataFrame are unique, you can create a dictionary from the 2 columns and then use that to map in the country, e.g.:

```
d = dict(zip(countrystations['Place'], countrystations['Country']))
```

And then:

```
txtmax = '\n{}, {}\n{}, {}\n{}, {}'.format(maxstat[0], d[maxstat[0]],
                                           maxstat[1], d[maxstat[1]],
                                           maxstat[2], d[maxstat[2]])
```